# Keep dynamic form field values after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using form with select dropdown. When user selects option, it gets posted to `ajax.php` via Ajax. The file then returns dynamic input fields. The `form.php` looks like this **before** option is selected:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <select name="raw_ids_array[]" class="select2" multiple="multiple" id="raw_ids_array"><option></option><option value="1">first</option><option value="2">second</option></select>
    <div id="raws_list_hidden"></div>
<input type="submit" id="submit_me" name="submit_me" value="go">
</form>
```

The `form.php` looks like this **after** option is selected:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <select name="raw_ids_array[]" class="select2" multiple="multiple" id="raw_ids_array"><option></option><option value="1">first</option><option value="2">second</option></select>
    <div id="raws_list_hidden"><input type="text" name="dynamic_field"></div>
<input type="submit" id="submit_me" name="submit_me" value="go">
</form>
```

I use this code to do Ajax posting:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
  function ajax_post_data(parameters) {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      cache: false,
      data: parameters,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#raws_list_hidden").html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  $('#raw_ids_array').on("change", function(e) {
  parameters=$("#myform").serialize();
  ajax_post_data(parameters);
  });
});
</script>
```

However, if form submission fails, I need all the previously selected options/entered values to be displayed again. So added this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  parameters=$("#myform").serialize();
  ajax_post_data(parameters);
  });
```

When `form.php` is submitted (gets "reloaded"), it posts selected options from `raw_ids_array[]` to `ajax.php`, which then adds dynamic fields into `raws_list_hidden` div again. The only thing which doesn't work - user's entered value from `dynamic_field` is NOT serialized; therefore, it becomes empty.

How should I modify the code, so values from dynamic fields also get posted to `ajax.php`?

P.S. I can serialize all fields if I use code:

```
$('#submit_me').click(function() {
    parameters=$("#myform").serialize();
  ajax_post_data(parameters);
});
```

but it's not useful because data is serialized **before** posting `form.php`, so I don't know if form will fail (in case some invalid values were submitted) or not.

Comment: The point of ajax is that it doesn't require the page to reload. Why not make the form use ajax to submit too? Then you would be able to provide success/failure and not lose submitted data as it wouldn't reload the page.

Comment: It's a good point, but I prefer only using ajax to add dynamic fields to forms, and then using standard HTML/PHP POST to submit forms.

Answer (score 1):

If understood you correctly, you're posting your form twice without noticing it.

To get it working, you'll first need to replace the input type submit in your form for another type of element, like the code example below, where I used *button* instead:

EDIT: added proper function call for the form and ajax posts.

```
<form id="myform">
    <select name="raw_ids_array[]" class="select2" multiple="multiple" id="raw_ids_array">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
    </select>
    <div id="raws_list_hidden"></div>

    <button id="submit_me" name="submit_me">go</button>

</form>
```

This will prevent your form to be submitted automatically When the button is pressed: we'll restrict the button's actions to what we write in our JS.

As you can see, there are no method or action properties for the form element either.

The idea of using ajax is exactly to NOT have to reload a page when something is submitted. Ajax will post the data and handle the results behind the curtins, so the user won't ever be redirected to another page nor anything will be automatically reloaded.

I believe if you keep your JS as:

```
function post_data(params, dest) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: dest+'.php',
        cache: false,
        data: params,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#raws_list_hidden').html(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('something went wrong - ', data);
        }
    });
}

$('#raw_ids_array').on("change", function(e) {
    parameters = $("#myform").serialize();
    post_data(parameters, 'ajax');
});

$('#submit_me').click(function() {
    parameters=$("#myform").serialize();
    post_data(parameters, 'form');
});
```

It will work.

On the "success" property of the ajax request declaration we'll deal with positive responses (http codes 200 to 299). To deal with errors (http codes 400 to 599), you can declare a function on the "error" property, like the example above.

For more info on JQuery Ajax: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp
For more information on http status codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

I hope this helped! :)

---

EDIT: Added proper function call for the form and ajax posts. If you want to deal with the post responses separately, you can either create two distinct functions to make the calls, or edit the code so you could send a callback functions:

```
function postData(params, dest, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: dest+'.php',
        cache: false,
        data: params,
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
    });
}

$('#raw_ids_array').on('change', function(e) {
    postData($('#myform').serialize(), 'ajax', ajaxSuccess, ajaxError);

    function ajaxSuccess(response) {
         $('#raws_list_hidden').html(response);
    }

    function ajaxError(response) {
         console.log('something went wrong with ajax post - ', response);
    }
});

$('#submit_me').on('click', function() {
    postData($('#myform').serialize(), 'form', formSuccess, formError);

    function formSuccess(response) {
         console.log('form submit worked successfully - ', response);
    }

    function formError(response) {
         console.log('something went wrong with form post - ', response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. When submit button is clicked, I need to submit data to form.php, not ajax.php

Comment: Then you can make both requests by ajax! ;) I've edited my answer to suit your needs, but I would consider refactoring it! :)

Comment: Avoiding submitting data directly through a submit button on a html form, will alow you to treat responses differently, will allow you to work with html templates, instead of processing html on the backend, will allow to validate data before submiting it... try it for a while and you'll find out many advantages on working like that =D